# Fastest way to keep two files in sync?

Tags: linux, sync

I care only about the same file stored in two different machines. I would like to keep changes in sync and as fast as possible. Would rsync as a daemon be up to it? Or is there something else I can use.

Comment: Unidirectional or bidirectional sync?

Comment: @cdhowie: bi-directional. I would rather not have one side pushing and polling changes due to speed considerations.

Comment: @MicyBart I mean will the file only ever change on one side, or do both sides need to sync changes to the opposite server?  (Is one side a read-only copy?)

Comment: @cdhowie: Ahh. The file will change on both sides.

Comment: @MicyBart Then you need to tackle the important question: what should happen if the same region of the file is simultaneously updated on both sides?

Comment: @cdhowie: Oh yes, for got that bit. The newer change will overwrite the older.

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for a network filesystem (NFS)... it will be much easier than maintaining error-free bi-directional replication using rsync.

Comment: @MicyBart: what if files were changed on both sides at exact same time (to nanosecond)? In general, this problem does *NOT* have simple solution.

Comment: ...and in addition to @mvp: what if the two computer clocks are not synchronized perfectly.

Comment: And even if clocks were perfect, there are limits imposed by physical laws. Light travels 30 cm in 1 nanosecond. So, if your computers are more than few meters apart, meaning of "my timestamp was earlier and thus my change to file wins" simply does make sense and cannot apply.

Comment: What about having only one real instance of the file, exporting (sharing) the file system that it's on, and having the other machine do a remote mount?

Answer (score 0):

You can use unison (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) with the --batch option. This will make a bidirectional sync over ssh or ftp.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `lsyncd` here : https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/

This is a daemon which keeps monitoring particular folders, and as soon as something changes in one of the folders, it spawns rsync for synchronization. It is pretty cool and robust. I've been using it without fail.

**UPDATE**

In case the files reside over network on 2 different systems, `syncthing` would be a better option.